# Add new node to k8s cluster which raised up by Rancher, without rancher ui

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

There is a k8s cluster, before that it was raised via Web UI Rancher 2.5. But the server with Rancher was deleted, there are no backups, the k8s cluster itself is working fine. We installed a new rancher and imported the current k8s cluster into it. Everything works well, but there is no way to add new nodes.
Can this be done via kubectl or some other tools and how?

I'm install new rancher and import existing k8s cluster. But can't find any way to add a new node to this cluster